# Absolute continuity as a condition for $F[f^{(k)}](\lambda)=(i\lambda)^k F[f](\lambda)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral

In read in Kolmogorov-Fomin's (p. 429 [here](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0,1976.pdf)) that *if function $f$ is such that $f^{(k-1)}$ is absolutely continuous on any interval and if* $f,...,f^{(k)}\in L_1(-\infty,\infty)$, [...] *we get* $$F[f^{(k)}](\lambda)=(i\lambda)^k F[f](\lambda)$$where $F[f]$ is the Fourier transform of $f$ defined by $F[f](\lambda):=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)e^{-i\lambda x}d\mu_x$. I think it is implicitly intended that **all** $f,...,f^{(k-1)}$ are absolutely continuous on any interval. Am I right? This is my opinion because, as it is presented in the text, this equality appears to be a consequence of the fact that if $f\in L_1(-\infty,\infty)$ is absolutely continuous on any interval and if $f'\in L_1(-\infty,\infty)$ then $F[f'](\lambda)=i\lambda F[f]$...

Does anybody know more about the fact and can confirm or refute what I think? Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, you can assume that $f$ is $k-1$ times continuously differentiable with absolutely continuous $f^{(k-1)}$.

Comment: @T.A.E. But I think it is also needed that $f,...,f^{(k-2)}$ are absolutely continuous, isn't that so? Without that hypothesis, I don't see how to derive the formula, which would be trivially proved by induction if $f,...,f^{(k-2)}$ are absolutely continuous...

Comment: Continuously differentiable implies absolutely continuous by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. However, the assumption that derivatives are globally $L^{1}$ is a completely different story.

Comment: Thank you so much! If $f^{(k-1)}$ is continuous I see that $\int_{-\infty}^x f^{(k-1)}(t)dt$ is absolutely continuous on any $[a,b]$ and it must be the same as $f^{(k-2)}$ since the primitive of such a function is uniquely determined up to a constant. Setting the primitive $\to0$ as $x\to-\infty$ uniquely determines the primitive.

Comment: If you want lower order derivatives to integrable, it will have to be assumed, not deduced. For example, if $f'$ is equal to $1/x^{3/2}$ for large $x$, then $f$ would be $-2/\sqrt{x}+C$ for large $x$ which would not be in $L^{1}$ even if $C=0$. The absolute continuity is assumed for all of the lower order derivatives, just like when you refer to $C^{2}$ or $C^{3}$. Absolute integrability is a separate assumption.

Comment: @T.A.E. I'm not sure I'm understanding: have I correctly understood that if $f,..,f^{(k)}\in L_1$ and $f^{(k-1)}$ is absolutely continuous then $F[f^{(k)}]=(i\lambda)^k F[f]$ (because $f^{(k-1)}$ absolutely continuous implies $f^{(k-2)}$ absolutely continuous and so there's no need to specify it as a condition for the consequent)?

Comment: If you assume $k$ times absolutely continuous and then add that all the derivatives are in $L^{1}$, then you get the setting you want for what you're doing. The derivatives will be locally $L^{1}$, but not necessarily globally $L^{1}$, which I think you want, unless I'm misreading.

Comment: Yes, I intended $L_1=L_1(\mathbb{R})$. Therefore "if $f,..,f^{(k)}\in L_1(\mathbb{R})$ and $f^{(k-1)}$ is absolutely continuous on any $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$ then $F[f^{(k)}]=(i\lambda)^k F[f]$" isn't true in general, but it's true that "if $f,..,f^{(k)}\in L_1(\mathbb{R})$ and $f,...,f^{(k-1)}$ are absolutely continuous on any $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$ then $F[f^{(k)}]=(i\lambda)^k F[f]$": have I correctly understood now? Thank you so much again!